# what is the best (simplest) way to store the state of a check box for seven days on phones without using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, state

I am building a simple app that should store the state of a switch / checkbook for a period of seven days. the only issue I have is that the website I am using to build said app doesn't accommodate for local storage on the phones. what is a good yet very simple way to store the switch / checkbook state without doing it through local storage or linking to an online database as I haven't the simplest clue of how to manage or set up let alone create a database. code options I have available to work with are HTML, CSS and javascript the website I am using is buildfire.

Comment: Java? or Javascript? Please understand that `Java != Javascript` and in fact they are quite different languages with their only similarities being that they both derive some syntax from C and share unfortunate similarities in their names. Note this is not a trivial question since tag accuracy is critical, and is one of the factors that matter most in getting the right experts attracted to your question.

Comment: How can you save a state despite of app's activity without storing it? You should consider about more flexible tools.

Comment: that's what I thought was unrealistic, and as such I was let to database usage as an alternative. I would rather not go down such a tricky path for somthing that should be quite simple @00Enthusiast

Comment: You could set a cookie and store the checkbox value in there and set the cookie to expire after 7 days - other than that if you're not using localstorage you've not got many options.

Comment: I think that shall have to be my method @RyanMcDonough, I am doing this all for fun I have NO experience in any code at all but all things considered I am not doing bad exactly or at least I wouldnt say. little over two days agao I wouldnt have even know what localstorage was let alone its purpose

Comment: @Ryan McDonough, i thought the same ,but cookie also should be stored in local storage.

Comment: in theory would it be posible to store the cookie on a server online with a peice of code to retrive that cookie each time as a function ? @RyanMcDonough

Comment: @LukeOwens that is not how cookies work. Cookies are stored client-side, and the cookies for the page are sent on every request to the web server. To save the values server side, you would need a method to save session state using the infrastructure provided by a server-side framework such as ASP.NET

Comment: @00Enthusiast localstorage vs local storage is different in the sense of a localstorage is using a SQLite Database on the client browser - whereas local storage is storing a cookie in the browser, but not in a SQLite DB.

Comment: would it work if i used a SQL server to store ASP.NET sesions state ? even if the thing i want the state saved from is in the app not on a website ? @ScottSimontis

Comment: SQL Server is one of the mechanisms by which ASP.NET can preserve session state. However, you would need to modify your app to transmit this data to the server so that the data could be stored. You would also need to handle identifying users and retrieving data for a specific user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I've built many apps on BuildFire. Here are my comments:

1. You can use LocalStorage on a plugin. However, multiple instances of your plugin with share the same LocalStorage so you need to be aware of this and give your variables distinct name like prepending them with the instanceId
2. You probably already know that DataStore is read-only on the device. You should use UserData (ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/User-Data:-Save-user-data-from-the-widget) this will allow you to save state per user per instance and cross device. It is used very similarly to DataStore yet allows a user to write to its own profile

```js
buildfire.userData.save (
  {checked:true} ///obj to save
  , userToken /// logged in user token
  , function(err,result){ ///callback
    }
)
```

Keep in mind that you will need to have the user be logged in. You can do this with the `auth` api
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth

```
buildfire.auth.login([options], callback);
```